# magento invoice edit text

Tags: magento

I am trying to to edit the text that appears in the invoice.ex: to change tax to     deposite or grand total to total due.Anyhow I don't want to change the amount of tax.I have tried searching on it a lot.I have I tried to make some changes in the mage/sales/model/order/invoice.php
and  mage/tax/block/sales/order/tax.php.I have also tried to change other mage files but of no use.I am a newbie please help.
     any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use either [inline translation](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/inline-translation-in-magento/) or [locale translation](http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/1442-Tutorial-Use-Magento-s-Translation-CSV-File-to-Change-Site-Labels).

The former is good for a quick change that only applies to the current install of Magento. The latter is better when you want to distribute your changes with extensions or themes to other sites.